# Check for even number fails with type problem

Tags: python

I am in a low-level coding class, and I have to create a program where the user enters an integer. The program then runs a series of loops to determine the smallest and largest values of the series entered by the user, as well as the count of even and odd numbers entered by the user, while also keeping a running total of all integers that have been entered. A blank line entered tells the program to stop and outputs the previously stated information. As the question states, I am not sure how to fix the error after the program enters the loop and runs one cycle. Here is the code so far:

```
counte=0
counto=0
sum=0
num=(input("Enter an integer (blank line to quit):"))
max=0
min=0
value=0
if(num==''):
    print("No input values were provided.\nQuitting the program!!!")
while (num!=''):
    value=int(input("Enter an integer (blank line to quit):"))
    if(num%2==0):
        counte+=1
    else:
        counto+=1
        sum+=value
        if(value>max):
            max=value
            if(value<min):
                min=value
    num=int(input("Enter an integer (blank line to quit:"))
    print("The smallest value is",min, "and the larges value is",max,".")
    print("The user entered",counte,"even, and",counto,"odd values.")
    print("The cumulative total is",total,".")
```

The syntax error that I get when I run the program is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "*sensitive information*", line 12, in <module>
        if(num%2==0):
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You are getting a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`. I think you meant `value % 2 == 0`, not `num % 2 == 0` (as `num` is a `str`, not an `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to an actual integer:

```
num = int(input("Enter an integer (blank line to quit):"))
```